# Zend_Form_Element label in row and element in row

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-decorators

how to decorate zend form element to put label in tr and element in tr

```
<tr><td><label>name</label></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
```

i use this code

```
$this->setElementDecorators(
    array('ViewHelper',
    array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'td','class'=>'element_td')),
    array('Label',array('tag'=>"td")),
    array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'tr'))
    )
);
```

but it produce label and elemment in same row[tr]
i want label in row and the element in another row how to do this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit tricky to do this with the decorators, but it's possible. Since you want to wrap two individual components within tags that are separate from each other, what you must do is first wrap one of them using the HtmlTag decorator, and after that build the other one by appending decorators after it (or optionally the other way around and prepending):

```
$this->setElementDecorators(array(
    array('Label'),
    array(array('labelTd'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'td','class'=>'label_td')),
    array(array('labelTr'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'tr','class'=>'label_tr')),
    array(array('elementOpenTr'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'tr','class'=>'element_tr','openOnly'=>true,'placement'=>'append')),
    array(array('elementOpenTd'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'td','class'=>'element_td','openOnly'=>true,'placement'=>'append')),
    array('ViewHelper', array('placement' => 'append')),
    array(array('elementCloseTd'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'td','closeOnly'=>true,'placement'=>'append')),
    array(array('elementCloseTr'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'tr','closeOnly'=>true,'placement'=>'append'))
));
```